# how to select all children and parents of a node in sql / oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, connect-by

I have a table  like below

MyTable

```
| ID     |  PARENT_ID |
-----------------------------
|   20      | null      |
|   40     | null      |
|   50     | null      |
|   70     | 122       |
|   100    | 40        |
|   102    | 4         |
|   126    | 100       |
|   9     | 50         |
|   122    | 40        |
|   123    | 9         |
```

I want to select hierarchy tree including all children  and parent like below for the given three children  126 ,70 and 123

**Expected output**

```
| ID     |  PARENT_ID |
-----------------------------
|   126     | 100      |
|   100     | 40       |
|   40      | null     |
|   70      | 122      |
|   122     | 40       |
|   123     | 9        |
|   9       | 50       |
|   50      | null     |
```

I have tried

```
select ID, PARENT_ID
from MyTable
start with ID=126 //this for example 
connect by prior ID=Parent;
```

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted thus far, it would help not only us help you by modifying your query, but also better explaining what you want because this doesn't really make any sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with hierarchical query using `CONNECT BY PRIOR` clause:

```
select * from MyTable start with id in (126,70,123)
         connect by prior parent_id = id;
```

NOTE: Since you have two nodes with `parent_id = 40`, you will get two rows with 40 as `ID` and null as `parent_id`. If you want to leave only one row, use `distinct` clause:

```
select distinct * from MyTable start with id in (126,70,123)
         connect by prior parent_id = id;
```